# Magento 1.9: Get product id from wishlist remove item event

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist

When I remove an item from wishlist, I need to get the product id of that item.
Anyone please help me on this.

See my code below:

config.xml

```
 <wishlist_item_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <data_wishlist_delete>
                        <class>data/observer</class>
                        <method>deleteFromWishlist</method>
                    </data_wishlist_delete>
                </observers>
 </wishlist_item_save_after>
```

Observer.php

```
public function deleteFromWishlist()
    {
        $item = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('item');
        $action = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();

        if (($action == 'remove') && !empty($item)) {

            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
            $query = 'SELECT product_id FROM wishlist_item WHERE wishlist_item_id = ' . $item . ' LIMIT 1';
            $id = $readConnection->fetchOne($query);
            echo 'Product Id: ' . $id . '<br/>';
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
```

The product id is not getting here is because the record in the **wishlist_item** table is deleting when we remove an item from wishlist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of checking routes and putting conditions in your observer event, you can add your observer on wishlist remove event `controller_action_predispatch_wishlist_index_remove`

```
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch_wishlist_index_remove>
        <observers>
            <data_wishlist_delete>
                <class>data/observer</class>
                <method>deleteFromWishlist</method>
            </data_wishlist_delete>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch_wishlist_index_remove>
</events>
```

And update your function to get Product Id like below.

```
public function deleteFromWishlist()
{
    $item = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('item');
    if($item){
        $item = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($item);
        $productId = $item->getProductId();
    }
}
```

Comment: do we have such event controller_action_predispatch_wishlist_index_remove in magento?? Because I'm not aware of it

Comment: @PavanKumar, Its not an actual event in Magento. The thing is that you can use an event on any of your action using `controller_action_` prefix. more description is here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7510618/1409718

Comment: @JaiminSutariya Thats a great solution. I didnt knew abt this till nw. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get your output in this way. Because you are saving the product to the wishlist and immediately you are trying to remove it by using SQL query. It will not work in this way. You need to override the `removeAction()` of wishlist from the file `app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\controllers\IndexController.php`.

```
public function removeAction()
    {
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            return $this->_redirect('*/*');
        }
        $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('item');
        $item = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($id);
        if (!$item->getId()) {
            return $this->norouteAction();
        }
        $wishlist = $this->_getWishlist($item->getWishlistId());
        if (!$wishlist) {
            return $this->norouteAction();
        }
        try {
            $event_data_array  =  array('cid' => '123'); //if require
            //defining the custom event
            Mage::dispatchEvent('my_custom_event', $event_data_array);
            $item->delete();
            $wishlist->save();
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(
                $this->__('An error occurred while deleting the item from wishlist: %s', $e->getMessage())
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(
                $this->__('An error occurred while deleting the item from wishlist.')
            );
        }

        Mage::helper('wishlist')->calculate();

        $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));
    }
```

Here we have adde our own custom event before deleting the item. So now by using this custom event, you can fetch the `product_id` by loading the wishlist collection.

problem solved.